# How to get float value in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

IR is as follows:

```
store float 1.000000e+00, float* %f, align 4, !dbg !860
%0 = load float, float* %f, align 4, !dbg !861
```

So if I know the name %f, how can I get 1.000000e+00 in both load and store instruction?

I know that `constant_int->getSExtValue()` can get int value. But I didn’t find similar function provided by ConstantFP.

Current code:

```cpp
if (auto *op = dyn_cast<LoadInst>(&I))
{
  Value *val = arg1;
  // HERE didn't work
  if (auto constant_int = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(val))
  {
    int number = constant_int->getSExtValue();
  }
  else if (auto constant_fp = dyn_cast<ConstantFP>(val))
  {
    // ??
  }
}

if (auto *op = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I))
{
  Value *val = op->getValueOperand();
  // HERE works!
  if (auto constant_int = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(val))
  {
    int number = constant_int->getSExtValue();
    errs() << "store " << number << ".\n";
  }
  else if (auto constant_fp = dyn_cast<ConstantFP>(val))
  {
    // ??
  }
}
```

Comment: What you want is to get the float value, you say. Try looking at the [ConstantFP](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantFP.html) documentation, see if you find a member function is either getFloatValue() or something like it…

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I find the function in APFloat::convertToDouble.

Comment: Well, the `load` instruction doesn't constant integer operands indeed. It is expected that your code doesn't work.